# How to make attribute setter send value through SQL function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to make an attribute setter in an ActiveRecord model wrap its value in the text2ltree() postgres function before rails generates its sql query.

For example,

```
post.path = "1.2.3"
post.save
```

Should generate something like

```
UPDATE posts SET PATH=text2ltree('1.2.3') WHERE id = 123 # or whatever
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You could write a Postgres function (stored procedure) and then just call `SELECT myfunc('1.2.3')`. I can provide an example if you are interested in that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** To achieve exactly what you are looking for above, you'd use this to override the default setter in your model file:

```
def path=(value)
  self[:path] = connection.execute("SELECT text2ltree('#{value}');")[0][0]
end
```

Then the code you have above works.

I'm interested in learning more about ActiveRecord's internals and its impenetrable metaprogramming underpinnings, so as an exercise I tried to accomplish what you described in your comments below. Here's an example that worked for me (this is all in post.rb):

```
module DatabaseTransformation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def transformed_by_database(transformed_attributes = {})

      transformed_attributes.each do |attr_name, transformation|

        define_method("#{attr_name}=") do |argument|
          transformed_value = connection.execute("SELECT #{transformation}('#{argument}');")[0][0]
          write_attribute(attr_name, transformed_value)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :path, :version
  include DatabaseTransformation
  transformed_by_database :name => "length" 

end
```

Console output:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > p = Post.new(:name => "foo")
   (0.3ms)  SELECT length('foo');
 => #<Post id: nil, name: 3, path: nil, version: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

In real life I presume you'd want to `include` the module in ActiveRecord::Base, in a file somewhere earlier in the load path. You'd also have to properly handle the type of the argument you are passing to the database function. Finally, I learned that `connection.execute` is implemented by each database adapter, so the way you access the result might be different in Postgres (this example is SQLite3, where the result set is returned as an array of hashes and the key to the first data record is 0].

This blog post was incredibly helpful:

http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/

as was the Rails guide for plugin-authoring:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Also, for what it's worth, I think in Postgres I'd still do this using a migration to create a query rewrite rule, but this made for a great learning experience. Hopefully it works and I can stop thinking about how to do it now.

Comment: A completely different way to do this that I just thought of would be to use Postgresql's query rewrite engine. A bit like using a trigger. You'd just set up the rule to rewrite updates such that the value was passed through the function. The upside is that your model is clean and you only do one call to the database. The downside is that it is not database-agnostic, which may obviously not be an issue in your case. I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to post an example, but here's a link to the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createrule.html

Comment: I feel like here should be a more efficient way of doing this that involves monkey patching ActiveRecord/Arel

Comment: If by "efficient" you mean performance, the query rewrite method is superior; I don't see how you can implement anything in Rails that would avoid two calls to the db. If by "efficient" you mean DRYer/more expressive (assuming this isn't the only place you ever want to do this), then I agree that's an option.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I meant more the second one. This question has more to do with understanding the internals of ActiveRecord/Arel than anything else. I upvoted your answer, though, because you do provide valuable information.