# How to query nested JSONB postgres in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I've a table called **Order** with a **jsonb** column type called **line_items**. The **line_items** column can contain nested values like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":9994857545813,
    "sku":"CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H",
  },
  {
    "id":9994857578581,
    "sku":"NATURAL-SHADOW_C1_24H",
  }
]
```

The above example has two line items in it but it can vary from 1 to any number of line items.

I need to query all orders that contains only 1 line item where sku = a particular value such as **CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H** as per above example.

So, the query should not match the above example but the following that has only 1 line item and sku=CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H

```
[
  {
    "id":9994857545813,
    "sku":"CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H",
  }
]
```

Can any help to write the query using Rails active record?

Comment: Use the JSON containment operator `@>`. Don't ever store tabular data as JSON!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out using the jsonb_array_length method:

```
Order
.where("line_items @> ?", [{sku: sku}].to_json)
.where("jsonb_array_length(line_items) = 1")
.count
end
```

The following resource was extremely helpful:
https://gist.github.com/mankind/1802dbb64fc24be33d434d593afd6221

Answer (score 0):

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6cf0fc71be5d8bd39b09ef3c3f3c4560)
You can call plpghsql in ruby.([How to call plpgsql functions from Ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499760/how-to-call-plpgsql-functions-from-ruby-on-rails))

---

sql query: `select jsonb_path_query(order_json,'$[*] ? (@.sku == "CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H")') from orders ;`

---

it's not easy to get it right, since some part of PL/pgsql function string even include 4 single quotes. Better use raise notice to test it step by step.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sku_CLIPPING_path (_sku text)
    RETURNS json
    AS $$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
    _returnjson jsonb;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%: _sku', $1;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', '$[*] ? (@.sku == ' || $1 || ')';
    RAISE NOTICE '%', $s$
    SELECT
        jsonb_path_query(order_json, $s$ || '''' || '$[*] ? (@.sku == ' || $1 || ')''' || ' from orders';
    _sql := $s$
    SELECT
        jsonb_path_query(order_json, $s$ || '''' || '$[*] ? (@.sku == ' || $1 || ')''' || ' )from orders';
    EXECUTE _sql
    USING _sku INTO _returnjson;
    RETURN (_returnjson::json);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

call it: `select * from get_sku_CLIPPING_path('"CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H"');`

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you don't have a nested json. You just have a json array with objects. Moreover your json objects can be representable as tabular. It's better to store those objects in another table and setup a one to many relationship.
You can have an "orders" table and an "order_details" table.

To get data you need, first we need to find records which have `"sku":"CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H"` then we need to parse json and get that object from line_items fields.

```
SELECT
    t.*
  FROM orders o,
  -- extract object from array of json objects 
  LATERAL jsonb_path_query(o.line_items, '$[*] ? (@.sku == $value)', '{"value" : "CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H"}') order_line,
  -- convert "sku":"NATURAL-SHADOW_C1_24H" into columns 
  LATERAL jsonb_to_record(order_line) as t(id bigint, sku text)
  WHERE
    -- find record which has "sku":"NATURAL-SHADOW_C1_24H"
    o.line_items @> '[{"sku":"NATURAL-SHADOW_C1_24H"}]';
```

Result will be like this;

```
           id | sku                 
------------- | --------------------
9994857545813 | CLIPPING-PATH_C2_24H
```

fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a6bf0b11041e95cf620956067ba642ca)